# insert multiple tables from a mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, database

running MySQL 5.5.8 I want to insert records into multiple tables via trigger. here is my trigger so far:

CREATE TRIGGER userlevel_insert
AFTER INSERT ON db.tablename
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT IGNORE INTO db.differenttable (col1,col2) VALUES (NEW.val1,2);

This works. no issue. However i want the insert to hit multiple tables. the table is actually the same structure, but in different databases. The following throws an error:

CREATE TRIGGER userlevel_insert
AFTER INSERT ON db.tablename
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT IGNORE INTO db.differenttable (col1,col2) VALUES (NEW.val1,2);
  INSERT IGNORE INTO db.secondtable (col1,col2) VALUES (NEW.val1,2);

The error is:
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'NEW.val1' in 'field list'

So how can i use a trigger to insert the same data into multiple tables?

Comment: I found this solution elsewhere:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution elsewhere: Set the new values as a variable, then insert into your tables. There may be performance issues, but my insert will only run once per day and the total number of records added will be minimal. I can see this being more efficient as a stored procedure, but this works for now.

```
CREATE TRIGGER doku_users_ins AFTER INSERT ON users_web.users
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN

                DECLARE new_pass VARCHAR(255);         -- choose the datatypes
                DECLARE new_email VARCHAR(255);        -- 
                DECLARE new_user INT;                  --

                SET new_pass = NEW.pass ; 
                SET new_email = NEW.email ;
                SET new_user = NEW.user ;

                INSERT INTO users_web.doku_users (login, pass, email)
                       VALUES (new_user, md5(new_pass), new_email);

                INSERT INTO users_web.doku_usergroup (uid, gid)
                       SELECT du.uid, '2' FROM doku_users du
                            WHERE new_user = du.login;

       END |
```

credit to ypercube on dba.stackexchange for the solution.